# Reactjs Search - Get data from sessionStorage and map through it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, session-storage, map-function

I am trying to create a search filter in Reactjs using react-search. I need to take data that is saved to sessionStorage and search through that. My issue is that I don't think I am mapping through the data correctly or setting an id correctly. When I type in the search box I'm thrown an error that says items.map is not a function. I need to know what I should put in my getItemsAsync function so that I can correctly grab the data from sessionStorage and map through it. Please post code samples in solution.

```
class TestComponent extends Component {

 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        repos: [],
    }
}

HiItems(items) {
    console.log(items);
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('List'));
}

getItemsAsync(searchValue, cb) {
   let items = sessionStorage.getItem('List');
      items.map(
         (i, data) => { return { id: i , value: data.List }})

      this.setState({ repos: items });
      cb(searchValue)  
} 

render () {
return (
  <div>
    <Search items={this.state.repos}
            multiple={true}
            getItemsAsync={this.getItemsAsync.bind(this)}
            onItemsChanged={this.HiItems.bind(this)} />
    <ul id="result"> {this.getItemsAsync} </ul>
  </div>
)
 } 
 }
  export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: what happens if you query sessionStorage.getItem('List') in debbuging mode ? Do you have any values there?

Comment: [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) stores data as strings. Use [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) to stringify and parse your data.

Answer (score 0):

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) stores data as strings. Use [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) to stringify and parse your data. So you get the error because `item` is a string or `undefined`, and there is no String#map

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3];
sessionStorage.setItem('List', JSON.stringify(list));
const result = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('List'));
console.log(result);
```

NB: Unfortunately the example does not work here due to `allow-same-origin` policy. But you can look at the following jsfiddle to see the result: https://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/w5z792jq/

Comment: OP is also not storing the result of the `map`

Comment: True, but that is not the cause of the thrown error.